# Quantifying How Much Better One Observation is Compared to Another

Tags: conditional-probability

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable where each outcome ($0$ or $1$) has a $50\%$ chance of occurring. We make two different observations $O_1$ and $O_2$ of a single outcome of $X$, where we have $P(X = 1 | O_1) = 0.5$ and $P(X = 1 | O_2) = 0.8$.

Since $O_1$ does not provide any new information about the outcome of the event but $O_2$ does, is there a nontrivial way to quantify the difference between $O_2$ and $O_1$?

An example can be this: imagine $X$ represents whether a room is free or occupied, with both outcomes having the same probability. Two different sensor suites make observations $O_1$ and $O_2$ of this room at the same time, and report back the conditional probabilities above. Based on this information, I would like to know if there is a way to differentiate between the two sensor suites, e.g. to say one is more reliable than the other.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "better"?

Comment: I suppose $O_2$ is better since it has more confidence in the outcome of $X$, but it may not be the right word. I guess I am looking for a way to quantify the difference between $O_1$ and $O_2$.

Comment: The meaning of this question is difficult to discern.  How are these conditional probabilities determined?  On what basis do you assert $O_1$ "does not provide any new information"? You have already asserted you know *all the properties of $X$*--it is completely determined from the information on the first line--so what would be the point of making observations?  The issue could be presented like this: you *know* you are flipping a fair coin.  You flip it twice.  Could you tell us what you might possibly have learned about this coin you didn't know before??

Comment: I guess I didn't phrase the question properly. $O_1$ and $O_2$ are two different observations of a single outcome of $X$. Let $X$ represent the fair coin. I flip it once, and two observers $O_1$ and $O_2$ provide the conditional probabilities above. I want to know if there is a way to differentiate between the two observers. The reason I say the first observation "does not provide any new information" is because that observation does not provide any new information about the outcome, aside from the fact that it's a fair coin. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: It makes some sense, but your assertion about relative amounts of information provided is either incorrect or meaningless.  The observers provide information about *themselves,* not about the coin, and however you might measure "information," they provide equivalent "amounts" of it.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Cross Validated. My answer doesn't really answer your question the way you'd like, but it was too long to put into a comment.

if O_1 and O_2 come from the same random variable how can they give different levels of information? Certainly, it is possible that P(X=1|O_1) is less than or greater for each observation, but that is because of the relationship between the random variable O to X, not the information contained in each sampled value of O.

For example, suppose you ran a regression of O against X and got some linear relationship B, a O_2 is bigger and B is positive then the chances of X would indeed be higher, by B amount. But O_1 and O_2 would all contribute the same amount of information as each other and every other observation in the sample.

The only way to make individual observations weigh more is to weigh them as such. This is perhaps the closest to what your question is asking for, but it's a stretch because but that's something you do to O, it does not depend on P(X=1|O). You can't make weights to get to a relationship B that you want. You can't weigh O_n based off of B, or P(X=1|O), itself.

You could, for example, use inverse variance weights to lessen the volatility of your estimate of B, or inverse probability weights to account for differening response rates of O. So, with inverse probability weights, let's say you have heaps and heaps of survey responses from a dominant group, and you get another response from that group, it's less "valuable" than getting a response from a rare minority.

So you find the census amount of that minority, and give each observation from that minority is (1/census amount)^-1. Because the census amount for the minority is much smaller than the dominant group, their weights will turn out to be much larger. And this will drag the estimate B up and down. But you weigh B to adjust for other things. Again, you don't weigh O_n based off of B, or P(X=1|O),  itself.

EDIT, to answer the edits: Thanks for clarifying, if I have interpreted you correctly, I think what you are looking for are the stock standard measures for evaluating a classification model. I.E. accuracy, or sensitivity and specificity, and precision and recall. This website has more than enough information on how to evaluate your model's predictions. But note, the accuracy of their predictions has nothing to do with what they predict (i.e. these conditional probabilities that are mentioned). For example, predicting 100% of rain tomorrow, doesn't mean there's a 100% chance of rain. That's the probability that sensor 1 thinks. if sensor 2 thinks there is only 10% chance of rain, and it turns out it doesn't rain tomorrow, sensor 2 is actually right. What needs to happen is they make a lot of predictions and you compare it against a lot of actual outcomes, and then evaluate the sensors using the aforementioned metrics. Pick the appropriate one for your situation. Again, this website is overflowing with posts in this area.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the question and added an example to hopefully clarify the problem.

Comment: @GoodarzMehr I have edited my response. I think I am getting what you are looking for now. I think. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm starting to get it now. If I want to compare the two observers (sensor suites) I have to make a lot of observations and compare them to the ground truth using one of those statistical measures you named, but if all I want to do is use this one measurement (assuming I know the ground truth) all I can say is one was $30\%$ more (or less) accurate than the other in predicting the outcome. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I think we are circling what you want, but we are not quite there yet. I recommend looking up estimate (a single prediction) vs estimator (a function, or model that estimates). Accuracy refers to the accuracy of an estimator, a single binary estimate is either right or wrong. We're getting there though. But it's too long of a conversation to have in comments. I also suggest looking those measures and specifically what they mean in *words* eg. sensitivity is "of the true positives, how many did I correctly predict?" and then come back with a fresh question.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your help!